# how to to tackle OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, python-imageio

I am trying to read the frames using imageio API. I have a reader as an object which I have received using `imageio.get_reader(video_path,"ffmpeg")`

```
nframes =int(reader.get_length())     
for ii in range(nframes):
    while frame_q.qsize() > 500: # so that we dont use huge amounts of memory
        time.sleep(1)
    cur_img = reader.get_next_data()
    frame_q.put(cur_img)
    #shape = cur_img.shape
    #noisy_img = np.uint8(cur_img.astype(np.float) + np.random.randn(*shape) * 20)
    #frame_q.put(noisy_img)
    if ii % 100 == 0:
        print("%i / %i frames in queue" % (ii, nframes))
print("All %i frames in queue" % (nframes))
```

Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prashantb/anaconda3/envs/demo/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/prashantb/anaconda3/envs/demo/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "multiprocess_detect_actions.py", line 61, in read_frames
    nframes =int(reader.get_length())
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Initially, the `nframe` was a float value then I tried to convert it into an integer but then I am getting an OverflowError.I will appreciate your advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: What is `reader`? Seems like it can be a generator with initially unknown length (presumably returning `inf` implies unknown, not infinite length, or you're going to be waiting a long time on infinite work). Knowing the API would be necessary to figure out how to handle the unknown/infinite reported length (Does `get_next_data` raise an exception when it runs out of data? Return a sentinel value? Something else?).

Comment: Is `reader` an instance of a class you've written? If so, you should figure out why its `get_length` method is returning infinity and fix that. If it comes from a library you're using, then you should check its API documentation to see what it means when it says it has an infinite length. Does it perhaps have an iterator-protocol API you could use insetead of `get_length()` and `get_next_data()`? If so, then `enumerate` could be your friend: `for ii, cur_img in enumerate(reader): #or enumerate(reader.something())`

Comment: @ShadowRanger reader is an object coming from imageio.get_reader() . get_next_data is not raising any exception.  and also no sentinel value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the new 2019 update 2.5.0 version from `imageio` : 
"The reader of the `ffmpeg` plugin now always reports `inf` as the number of frames. Use `reader.count_frames()` to get the actual number, or estimate it from the `fps` and duration in the meta data."
[imageio update](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes.html#version-2-5-0-06-02-2019)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, float type can be [infinity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). To fixe your bug, you check if the value is `inf` ou `-inf` before convert to int:

```py
def float_to_int(x):
    if x == float('inf') or x == float('-inf'):
        return float('nan') # or a large value you choose
    return int(x)
```

As @ShadowRanger noted, this solution just prevent the `OverflowError` error. You should investigate on the `reader` to fix the problem of infinite float.

Comment: Given that they turn around and plug this into `range`, you're just postponing the error by a line. There is a fundamental flaw with trying to do infinite work; odds are they're misusing their API.